# Handling exceptions in Scala collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections

You have a Scala collection (an iterator, in this case) that you wish to `filter` or `map`, where the function doing so can raise an exception.  You don't want the entire resulting collection being thrown out - only that member.  How do you do that?

I tried doing something like:

```
 collection.filter(Try(_.predicate))
```

but wasn't able to get that to work (and am not sure that that's the proper idiom in the first place!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on which you want to do. In the case of `filter`, the predicate still needs to be boolean, and `Try[T]` is most certainly not. `Try` does have handy `getOrElse` and `toOption` methods which could help us convert cases of `Failure` to `None`.

```
collection.filter(x => Try(predicate).getOrElse(false))
```

For `map` if you wish to throw out the failures, you can do something like this:

```
collection.flatMap(x => Try(...).toOption)
```

Comment: No need for `toOption` in your first example

Answer (score 6):

You're very close. Try something like:

```
collection.filter(x => Try(x.predicate).getOrElse(false))
```

Comment: Ah, I almost beat you to it, but your `filter` is better. I carelessly overlooked `getOrElse`.